# Alternative To Passing A DbContext object To Parallel Task

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parallel-processing, dbcontext

I have a scenario which involves performing the same processing action on a list of email messages. In order to speed up the processing I'm looking at using a Parallel.ForEach on my collection of mail items. The loop creates an instance of my mail item processing (clsMailItemProcess) class and passeses the mail item to it and process it.

The rules for processing each mail item are contained in a database schema, which allows for easier configuration of the rules. There are a number of rules to identify a reference number in the email, with each rule having a number of possible methods to identify the number. The task loops through the rules, and then processes the email based on which rule was matched first.

I am looking for some help as to the best way to use the DbContext.

- Should I create it outside the Parallel.ForEach and then pass a
  reference to the clsMailItemProcess class? From what I'm reading this
  could cause problems as DbContext is not thread safe, which may
  explain the errors I'm seeing on rare occasions, although it works
  with no problems 95% of the time. I assumed (perhaps mistakenly, I'm new to EF) that this would reduce the database calls)
- Should I create a new DbContext inside my clsMailItemProcess class
  and use it within that? This would increase the calls to the database
- Should I create the DbContext and convert its rules to objects that I
  could then pass around my application as needed

I should point out my DbContext does not change and no changes are written back to the database.

Comment: If you pass a context into a parallel `ForEach`, you're going to have problems - `DbContext` is not thread safe and will explode.

Comment: So what is the cost of the creating/reading of these rules relative to each single task and how much are you aiming for? As in, how much time does it take now, and what time do you need to satisfy your requirements?

Comment: I've not yet timed the creating/reading of the threads; was going to be my task for tomorrow. My main aim was to reduce the number of database calls to the minimum just to keep traffic to a minimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

> > I should point out my DbContext does not change and no changes are written back to the database.

Then:

> > Should I create the DbContext and convert its rules to objects that I could then pass around my application as needed

Yes.  Do that.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of assumed that I should do this, but wanted some confirmation of my ideas. It turned out it wasn't a big code change as I'd thought it might be.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a new DbContext within my Parallel.ForEach call.  Passing around a context to multiple threads can be problematic, especially if your rules have some type of side effects with respect to dirtying the context.

Are you sure this needs to be done in parallel?  In some of my pet projects where I've needed to solve a similar worker problem.  I would have a class that would poll a collection for changes.  When the class saw that it had work to do, it would fire off the clsMailItemProcess with it's new workload.

That would help cut down on complexity (well, it was supposed to) as well as let me isolate my clsMailItemProcess code.

Comment: There are no side effects. Processing each mail item can take up to 4 or 5 seconds, depending on what the mail item is and what attachments it has. Given there will be several hundred mail items per hour, I wanted to ensure they were processed as quickly as possible, although no one has yet defined how often they want to process the mailbox.